# Build interactive map from python

Tags: python, openstreetmap, mapbox, plotly

I am trying to build webpage showing an interactive map (taking up 100% of the page) where I present points or lines with information. Plotly seems perfect for this and I really like its visualization but it does however not have support for maps such as Open Street Map built in, it uses Mapbox for this. I don't have anything against Mapbox, but from what I can find it is free of charge up to a certain numbers of views (while it uses OSM).

Simply said: is there an easy (as open source and free to use) way using python to build such a webpage with a map that shows information?

Comment: Can't you just change the tile source so that it uses OSM's tile servers instead of MapBox'? Also note that OSM servers have a [tile usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/) as well. If you have too many requests then you have to run your own tile server.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the limits of the OSM servers policy. Not that come close to the limits, the webpage will only be used by maybe 10 or 20 people a few times per week. In that case I could as well use MapBox, but can I plot the output to html when using MapBox as well? And if I do want to change tile servers, how would I do this?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to configure the tile source for plotly, I've never worked with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed! You can use Mapbox GL JS without plotly. There are example of html code in here that will create these full sized maps for you. They can be satellite or just a plain map.

Drawing lines:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-line/

Creating a popup onclick:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-click/

Comment: It's better to explain the issue here and give some code examples than just pasting the link to external service.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use OSM maps free of charge without restrictions or a Mapbox API account in Plotly and Dash, see https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-layers/:

> Base Maps in layout.mapbox.style
>
> The accepted values for layout.mapbox.style are one of:
>
> - "white-bg" yields an empty white canvas which results in no external HTTP requests
> - **"open-street-map", "carto-positron", "carto-darkmatter", "stamen-terrain", "stamen-toner" or "stamen-watercolor" yeild maps composed of raster tiles from various public tile servers which do not require signups or access tokens**
> - "basic", "streets", "outdoors", "light", "dark", "satellite", or "satellite- streets" yeild maps composed of vector tiles from the Mapbox service, and do require a Mapbox Access Token or an on-premise Mapbox installation.
> - A Mapbox service style URL, which requires a Mapbox Access Token or an on-premise Mapbox installation.
> - A Mapbox Style object as defined at https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/

Here is a code example from the same plotly documentation that uses the OSM basemap without any authetification token:

```py
import pandas as pd
us_cities = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/us-cities-top-1k.csv")

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(us_cities, lat="lat", lon="lon", hover_name="City", hover_data=["State", "Population"],
                        color_discrete_sequence=["fuchsia"], zoom=3, height=300)
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

As for builing an actual website, I recommend using Dash, which is a webserver well integrated with plotly.